# Eclipse Show Error after ADT update

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

i have update Android Development Toolkit  for my eclipse.
the eclipse doent show up eroor(exclamatory mark) and doent predict the error,
it shows error only after running the project. how to solve this?
thanks in advance.....

Comment: It should tell you what the error is.  What does it say is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Build Automatically option selected -

[image]